# SSL - error 0D0680A8 and 0D07803A when try to convert crt file to pem file using OpenSSL

Tags: linux, openssl, ssl-certificate, debian, x509

I try to generate new .pem file from a .crt file with *OpenSSL*.

When I execute this command line, I have an error.

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in file.crt -out file.crt -text
```

The message error:

```
140074298443072:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
140074298443072:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=X509
```

If I execute this command line, it is work:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in file.crt -out file.pem -text
```

However, when I try to execute this one:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in file_2.crt -out file_2.pem -text
```

I have this error:

```
unable to load certificate
139808179582272:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1149:
139808179582272:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:309:Type=X509
```